# I try to convert a String to Date format in java but has an exception

Tags: java, string, date, exception, format

I try to convert `String` to `Date` format but I got an exception!

Here is my code:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
startDate = format.parse(startDateString);
```

it should convert `"14-MAY-2004"` to `Date`. Thanks.

Comment: "it got an exception", can you be a bit more specific about that?

Comment: You have : `dd-MMM-yyyy` it should be `dd-MM-yyyy` for date. 
If you want to have it with name of the MONTH. You have to Use LocalDate and the format "dd-LLLL-yyyy'

Comment: *What* is the exception?

Comment: @Luxusproblem nope. MM means a numeric representation of month. "MAY" is MMM

Comment: you want final date to be in dd-MMM-yyyy format? or your input string is in dd-MMM-yyyy format and want it to be converted to date of any format?

Comment: This may behave locale -specific; did you specify an English locale? See my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57615971/java-simpledateformat-throwing-parseexception-unparseable-date-on-windows-but-n/57616212#57616212

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: @Stultuske java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "14-MAY-2004"

Comment: @akuzminykh java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "14-MAY-2004"

Comment: @NKR the String is in dd-MMM-yyyy (14-MAY-2004) format and i want to convert it to Date format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### java.time

I recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date work.

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .parseCaseInsensitive()
            .appendPattern("d-MMM-uuuu")
            .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);

    String startDateString = "14-MAY-2004";
    LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.parse(startDateString, dateFormatter);

    System.out.println(startDate);
```

Output is:

> 2004-05-14

Only if you indispensably need a `Date` object for a legacy API not yet upgraded to java.time, convert:

```
    Instant startOfDay = startDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();
    Date oldfashionedDate = Date.from(startOfDay);

    System.out.println(oldfashionedDate);
```

Output in my time zone:

> Fri May 14 00:00:00 CEST 2004

### What went wrong in your code?

It’s almost certainly a locale problem. You didn’t specify a locale and hence no language for the month name or abbreviation. Always do that when the date string includes text in some language. Your `SimpleDateFormat` was using the default formatting locale of your JVM, and if that was a non-English-speaking locale, parsing was deemed to fail with an exception as you mentioned.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- Similar question: [Java - Unparseable date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154772/java-unparseable-date)

Answer (score 0):

From the statment "it should convert 14-MAY-2004 to date" i assume your input string is 14-MAY-2004 and you want this string to be converted to Date

```
String js="14-May-2004";
        Date dt=new Date(js);
        LocalDateTime localDateTime=dt.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime();
        localDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy"));//or in the same format use- "dd-MMM-yyyy"
```